# Material UI button rendered with span that is not clickable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a site using material-UI and have run into a bit of a snag. It seems that the button is being rendered with a span element around the button's text. This makes it so the click event only fires when you click outside the span element.

As you can imagine it's not the greatest UI to have users click buttons that don't do anything. I am sure that I am not the first one to go through this, is there a way that I can propagate the event down to the child element programmatically? Below is my component snipit:

```
import withRoot from '../onepirate/modules/withRoot';
// --- Post bootstrap -----
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useStyles } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Typography from '../onepirate/modules/components/Typography';
import AppFooter from '../onepirate/modules/views/AppFooter';
import AppForm from '../onepirate/modules/views/AppForm';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import MuiTextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';
import WorkIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Work';
import BeachAccessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/BeachAccess';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';


const Tickets = props => {
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        button: {
          margin: theme.spacing(1),
          backgroundColor: "#ff3366",
          color: "#000000"

        },
        input: {
          display: 'none',
        },
        ListItemText: {
            marginLeft: 105,

        }
      }));

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AppForm>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom marked="center" align="center">
                        Order Tickets
                </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" align="center">
                        <Link href="/premium-themes/onepirate/sign-in/" underline="always">
                            Already have an account?
            </Link>
                    </Typography>
                </React.Fragment>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                        <List className={classes.root}>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Button 
                                variant="contained" 
                                className={classes.button} 
                                onClick={props.quantity} 
                                id="basic">
                                    Add
                                </Button>
                                <ListItemText 
                                primary="Basic" 
                                secondary="$450" 
                                className={classes.ListItemText}/>
                                {props.init.basic}
                            </ListItem>
                            <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
                            <ListItem>
                            <Button 
                            variant="contained" 
                            className={classes.button} 
                            onClick={props.quantity} 
                            id="exec" >
                                    Add
                                </Button>
                                <ListItemText 
                                primary="Executive" 
                                secondary="$550" 
                                className={classes.ListItemText}/>
                                {props.init.exec}
                            </ListItem>
                            <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
                            <ListItem>
                            <Button 
                            variant="contained" 
                            className={classes.button} 
                            onClick={props.quantity} 
                            id="vip">
                                    Add
                                </Button>
                                <ListItemText 
                                primary="VIP" 
                                secondary="$750"
                                className={classes.ListItemText}/>
                                {props.init.vip}
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>
                        <Typography variant="h2">
                            {`Total: $ ${(props.init.basic * 450) + (props.init.exec * 550) + (props.init.vip * 750)}`}
                        </Typography>
                        <Button
                            className={classes.button}
                            size="large"
                            color="secondary"
                            fullWidth
                            onClick={props.price}
                            id=""
                            >
                            {'Proceed to Checkout'}
                            </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </AppForm>
            <AppFooter />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default withRoot(Tickets);
```

And the rendered HTML output of one of the buttons:

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root-307 MuiButton-root-290    makeStyles-button-87 MuiButton-contained-298"
 tabindex="0"           
 type="button" 
 id="exec">

 <span class="MuiButton-label-291">Add</span> 

 <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-391"></span>

 </button>
```

Comment: As I understood, you are saying that your onClick event fires only when clicked outside the text in the button?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's because the framework is rendering the text inside of a span element (which I believe is an illegal element to place inside a button). It would be great if a prop could remove it but any workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Putting a `span` within a `button` is perfectly valid and does not prevent the click from propagating ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-d685x)). If the click isn't working on the text, it is something specific to your code/environment. Please try to reproduce this behavior in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was not able to reproduce, going to review my code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Material UI v4 accepts both `e.target.value` and `e.currentTarget.value`.

However, if you use `e.target.value` to deliver buttons' value, and click on the `span` node (nested inside of button), the value won't be taken from the `button` node that you assigned it to, but the `span` HTML element that does not have the `value` property and so the value is `undefined`.

To remedy the above, use `e.currentTarget.value` as it seems to pick up the `value` property from the button, even if you click on the `span` node.

Below sandbox should show you the difference in using `e.target.value` and `e.currentTarget.value` with material UI buttons.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-glitter-wqtt3?file=/src/App.js

Open up the console and click interchangeably on `span` and `button` elements and observe logs when you do that.

I have not tested the latest v5 from Material UI, it could be that they changed (improved?) this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping span and button inside a div or other wrapper component and call onClick on that